# Add Azure Cloud Service to existing project

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I need to add azure cloud service for sending emails. Here is example how to do it http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email .

But i have one question - Do I need to create Azure Service with Asp.Net Role and Worker Role or i can use just Worker Role for service? Asp.Net Role just for UI?

Thanks

Comment: Your cloud service can only contain a worker role. There is absolutely no need to have a web role if you don't require it.

Comment: @GauravMantri, Thanks. Now i understand it completely